# Почему может не работать цвет родительского элемента и css из переменной?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
в<ul className={styles.navList}>
                        <li className={styles.navListItem}>
                        <NavLink to="/" className={({isActive})=> isActive ? activeLink : normalLink}>
                            
                            Projects
                        </NavLink>
                           
                        </li>

                        <li className={styles.navListItem}>

                        <NavLink to="/skills" className={({isActive})=> isActive ? activeLink : normalLink}>
                            Skills
                        </NavLink>
                        </li>

                        <li className={styles.navListItem}>

                        <NavLink to="/contacts" className={({isActive})=> isActive ? activeLink : normalLink}>
                            Contacts
                        </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Вот код и вот константы:

```
const activeLink = 'classNames(styles.navListLink, styles.navListLinkActive)'
    const normalLink = 'styles.navListLink'
```

проблема в том что по css текст должен быть белым и с подчёркиванием псевдоэлемента, но получается это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он цвета родительского элемента и css из переменной не работает

Comment: А CSS-то где потерялся?

Comment: Хелловин вроде через неделю только, рановато для чертовщины

Comment: И что у вас такое интересное в переменной `const activeLink`? Скорее всего вам надо сделать так: `className={ isActive ? styles.navListLinkActive : styles.navListLink }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас почему-то константы - это обычные строки.

```
const activeLink = 'classNames(styles.navListLink, styles.navListLinkActive)'
const normalLink = 'styles.navListLink'
```

Перепишите их вот так без кавычек:

```
const activeLink = classNames(styles.navListLink, styles.navListLinkActive);
const normalLink = styles.navListLink;
```